# Реализация бронирования автомобилей для сайта каршеринга на Django

Tags: django

Я разрабатываю сайт, похожий на приложения для каршеринга на мобильных устройствах. Суть вопроса стоит в реализации бронирования и последующей аренды автомобиля на время.
Допустим: человек бронирует автомобиль, бронь действует до подтверждения пользователем непосредственной посадки в авто либо через 20 минут удаляется сама. Если же человек подтвердил посадку начинактся аренда автомобиля с учётом времени её начала и, после, временем ее окончания(как только человек нажмет "завершить аренду"). После окончания аренды нужно получить стоимость поездки анализируя полное время аренды и, в соответствии с трафиком, выдача счёта.
Вопрос задаю людям, которые пишут на django не первый раз и могут подсказать варианты решения для этого вопроса(я рассматриваю вариант сессий, но т.к. я практически ничего не знаю о django, то не совсем понимаю как с их помощью реализовать данную систему) . Заранее спасибо

Comment: *т.к. я практически ничего не знаю о django* - может стоит начать с того, что почитать про django. А то как вы разберетесь, что вам посоветуют про область, в которой вы не понимаете?

Comment: Эта информация значимая для конкурентных запросов и поэтому сессии не годятся совсем. Пиши в модель

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Вопрос не понятен, поскольку включает большое количество подзадач. Начните реализовывать, появится конкретный вопрос, задавайте.

Comment: Благодарю, буду пробовать моделями.